# css dimensions bug in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome

Is there a new bug in Chrome 16.0.912.63?

This is my CSS:

```
#wholesale {
margin: 0px 0px;
width: 930px;
text-align: center;
display: table;
border-top: 12px solid;
line-height: 24px;
}
```

but I get a box that is 12px too ***wide*** (942px):

Removing the border-top declaration will result in the correct width (930px).
You can see this using the above mentioned version of Chrome on this [page](http://shop.eboy.com/products/rio-poster).

Firefox 8.0.1 and Safari Version 5.1.2 (7534.52.7) and older versions of Chrome worked just fine.

Comment: I don't really understand whats the problem ? If you add 12px the element gets 12px "wider" ?!

Comment: I have not tried it, but if it is true then it does sound like a bug to me.

Comment: This definitely is a bug, [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cz8Tb/) shows it a bit more clearly - a top border of 200px adds 200px to the width of the div, it only happens if `display` is set to `table`.

Comment: I created a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=108528&q=border-top%20border-bottom%20table&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary) for this.

Comment: wow very interesting: i'm getting similar results, this fiddle compares the results with border-right: 0px explicitly set: http://jsfiddle.net/c4urself/bB6nU/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why Chrome is doing this, but if you remove display:table, it fixes your problem.

You don't really need display:table since your content in #wholesale, #newshead and #carthead are all block elements.